# Python Pyramid app, Uncaught TypeError: $(...).jstree is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, pyramid

I have a very simple Python application built with Pyramid, Jinja2, JS, etc.  I'm trying to use JsTree https://www.jstree.com/docs/config/ to show a checkbox list.  The issue is it seems no matter what workarounds I try i'm running into issues calling the functions from jstree.min.js.

From my understanding I just need to import jQuery, and then the plugin jsTree, and finally my JS code that calls the jsTree functions.  I've confirmed in the dev console that the JS is actually being imported in order but i continue to get the error that jstree is not a function.  Is there something specific with the Pyramid web server that could be causing these issues?

i've seen several workarounds like setting
    $=jQuery.noConflict();
or something like

```
  var jq=jQuery.noConflict();

  jq(document).ready(function () { 
       ('#jstree_demo_div').jstree(); 
  });
```

I've also tried appending the jstree.js file to the end of the jQuery file without success.  I'm not sure where to turn as it seems like this shouldn't be a difficult thing to do.  Is there something specific about Pyramid or jinja2 i'm missing here?

EDIT:
I suspect that this has something to do with the fact that i'm trying to do this from within the success portion of the jQuery.Ajax({}); function in the getDevFiles function, are the AJAX containers emptied for the entire duration of the call?  or am I missing something obvious there that would explain why jstree() isn't available?

Here is what my jinja template layout.jinja2 looks like....

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{request.locale_name}}">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="pyramid web application">
    <meta name="author" content="Pylons Project">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{request.static_url('hello_ajax:static/pyramid-16x16.png')}}">
    {% block javascript %}
      <script type="text/javascript"> 
        {% include "static/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" %}
      </script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        {% include "static/jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.js" %}
      </script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        {% include "static/jstree/dist/jstree.min.js" %}
      </script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        {% include "static/hello_ajax.js" %}
      </script>
    {% endblock %}
    <title>Starter Scaffold for The Pyramid Web Framework</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="//oss.maxcdn.com/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this scaffold -->
    <link href="{{request.static_url('hello_ajax:static/theme.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{{request.static_url('hello_ajax:static/jstree/dist/themes/default/style.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="//oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js" integrity="sha384-0s5Pv64cNZJieYFkXYOTId2HMA2Lfb6q2nAcx2n0RTLUnCAoTTsS0nKEO27XyKcY" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="//oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min.js" integrity="sha384-f1r2UzjsxZ9T4V1f2zBO/evUqSEOpeaUUZcMTz1Up63bl4ruYnFYeM+BxI4NhyI0" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="starter-template">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-2">
              <img class="logo img-responsive" src="{{request.static_url('hello_ajax:static/ITBIA.png')}}" alt="pyramid web framework">
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-10">
            {% block content %}
                <p>No content</p>
            {% endblock content %}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
        <div class="row2">
          {% block content2 %}
            <p>No content</p>
          {% endblock content2 %}
        </div>
          <div class="links">
            <ul>
              <li class="current-version">Generated by v1.9.1</li>
              <li><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-bookmark icon-muted"></i><a href="https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.9-branch/">Docs</a></li>
              <li><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog icon-muted"></i><a href="https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid">Github Project</a></li>
              <li><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe icon-muted"></i><a href="https://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=pyramid">IRC Channel</a></li>
              <li><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home icon-muted"></i><a href="https://pylonsproject.org">Pylons Project</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="copyright">
            Copyright &copy; Pylons Project
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="//oss.maxcdn.com/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha384-aBL3Lzi6c9LNDGvpHkZrrm3ZVsIwohDD7CDozL0pk8FwCrfmV7H9w8j3L7ikEv6h" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="//oss.maxcdn.com/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-s1ITto93iSMDxlp/79qhWHi+LsIi9Gx6yL+cOKDuymvihkfol83TYbLbOw+W/wv4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and then my other template mytemplate.jinja2:

```
{% extends "layout.jinja2" %}



{% block content%}
  <div class="content">
      <h1><span class="font-semi-bold">EBIA-IT</span> <span class="smaller">BI&A Portal POC</span></h1>
      <p class="lead">Welcome to <span class="font-normal">{{project}}</span>, an&nbsp;application generated&nbsp;by<br>the <span class="font-normal">Pyramid Web Framework 1.9.1</span>.</p>
      <h1>POC for Ajax Win Server File Interacton Begin:</h1>
      <button onclick="do_some_ajax()">Do some ajax</button>
      <div id="AjaxResponse"></div>
  </div>
{% endblock content %}

{% block content2 %}
  <button onclick="getDevFiles()">Update List of Files in Dev</button>
  <h1> Files in Dev: </h1>
  <div id="FileList">No Content</div>
  <ul id = "root"></ul>

  <div id="jstree_demo_div"></div>

{% endblock content2 %}
```

Here is my JS (some of what I've tried is commented out, but i left if there for some context):

```
function do_some_ajax(){
    jQuery.ajax({
        url     :   'ajax_view',
        type    :   'POST',
        dataType:   'json',
        success :   function(data){
            alert("Success.  Got the message:\n" + data.message)
            document.getElementById("AjaxResponse").innerHTML = data.message
        }
    });
}

//$(function () { $('#jstree_demo_div').jstree(); });

//$(document).ready(function () { $('#jstree_demo_div').jstree(); });
//$('#jstree_demo_div').jstree();
/*jQuery(document).ready(function ($) { 
    $('#jstree_demo_div').jstree(); 
});*/

//$=jQuery.noConflict();

/* jq(document).ready(function () { 
    jq('#jstree_demo_div').jstree(); 
});*/

function getDevFiles(){
    jQuery.ajax({
        url     :   'get_dev_files',
        type    :   'POST',
        dataType:   'json',
        success :   function(data){
            alert("Files in Dev Updated.");
            $('#jstree_demo_div').jstree(); 

            /*
            $('#using_json').jstree({ 'core' : {
                'data' : [
                   'Simple root node',
                   {
                     'text' : 'Root node 2',
                     'state' : {
                       'opened' : true,
                       'selected' : true
                     },
                     'children' : [
                       { 'text' : 'Child 1' },
                       'Child 2'
                     ]
                  }
                ]
            } });*/

            // Function to add an item to our JSON Lists
            /*function addItem(parentUL, branch) {
                alert(branch);
                alert(branch.find(children));
                for (var key in branch.children) {
                    alert(branch.children);
                    alert(2);
                    var item = branch.children[key];
                    $item = $('<li>', {
                        id: "item" + item.id
                    });
                    $item.append($('<input>', {
                        type: "checkbox",
                        id: "item" + item.id,
                        name: "item" + item.id
                    }));
                    $item.append($('<label>', {
                        for: "item" + item.id,
                        text: item.title
                    }));
                    parentUL.append($item);
                    if (item.children) {
                        var $ul = $('<ul>', {
                            style: 'display: none'
                        }).appendTo($item);
                        addItem($ul, item);
                    }
                }
            }
            //var json = JSON.stringify(data.DevFileList, null);

            $(function () {
                addItem($('#root'), data.DevFileList);
                $(':checkbox').change(function () {
                    $(this).closest('li').children('ul').slideToggle();
                });
                $('label').click(function(){
                    $(this).closest('li').find(':checkbox').trigger('click');
                });
            });

            */
            //$("#FileList").append(jsonPretty);
        }

    })

}
```

And finally my views.py file if that's at all relevant:
from pyramid.view import view_config

```
import os
import json
import errno

#@view_config(route_name='home', renderer='templates/mytemplate.jinja2') useing chameleon instead of jinja2
@view_config(route_name='home', renderer='templates/mytemplate.jinja2')
def my_view(request):
    return {'project': 'File Version Factory'}

# Handle our ajax call
@view_config(route_name='generate_ajax_data', renderer='json')
def my_ajax_view(request):
    return {'message': "Just did some work on the server side as we received your AJAX call."}
"""
def path_to_dict(path):
    d = {'name': os.path.basename(path)}
    if os.path.isdir(path):
        d['type'] = "directory"
        d['children'] = [path_to_dict(os.path.join(path,x)) for x in os.listdir\
(path)]
    else:
        d['type'] = "file"
    return d
"""
def path_hierarchy(path):
    hierarchy = {
        'type': 'folder',
        'name': os.path.basename(path),
        'path': path,
    }

    try:
        hierarchy['children'] = [
            path_hierarchy(os.path.join(path, contents))
            for contents in os.listdir(path)
        ]
    except OSError as e:
        if e.errno != errno.ENOTDIR:
            raise
        hierarchy['type'] = 'file'

    return hierarchy

# Files in Dev Ajax Call...
@view_config(route_name='get_Files', renderer='json')
def getDevFiles(request):
    directory = json.dumps(path_hierarchy("C:\\Users\\skcunnin\\Desktop\\Dev"))
    print(directory)
    return{'DevFileList': directory}
    #return{'DevFileList': directory}
```

All i'm really doing here is when the 'Update List of Files in Dev' button is clicked then execute the getDevFiles() function from hello_ajax.js (via ajax so we don't need to reload the page).  Where i'm running into trouble is
    $('#jstree_demo_div').jstree();

Throws an error in the console:

```
(index):18768 Uncaught TypeError: jq(...).jstree is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> ((index):18768)
    at c (jquery.min.js:4)
    at Object.add [as done] (jquery.min.js:4)
    at init.ready (jquery.min.js:4)
    at Object.success ((index):18767)
    at c (jquery.min.js:4)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:4)
    at k (jquery.min.js:6)
    at XMLHttpRequest.r (jquery.min.js:6)
(anonymous) @ (index):18768
c @ jquery.min.js:4
add @ jquery.min.js:4
ready @ jquery.min.js:4
success @ (index):18767
c @ jquery.min.js:4
fireWith @ jquery.min.js:4
k @ jquery.min.js:6
r @ jquery.min.js:6
XMLHttpRequest.send (async)
send @ jquery.min.js:6
ajax @ jquery.min.js:6
getDevFiles @ (index):18759
onclick @ (index):18877
```

Comment: Try this: `$('#jstree_demo_div').jstree();`

Comment: Unfortunately i've already given that a go, if you take a look at the AJAX Success function:
` function getDevFiles(){
    jQuery.ajax({
        url     :   'get_dev_files',
        type    :   'POST',
        dataType:   'json',
        success :   function(data){
            alert("Files in Dev Updated.");
            $('#jstree_demo_div').jstree(); `

Sorry if i wasn't clear, but that's exactly the line that's throwing the error.